# Android static class null on first run

Tags: java, android, initialization, static-classes

I have a class with all static members which I need to use for saving my datas in a wide scope, using them in all activities.
Now, all is working fine after the first run of the application, but this first time run always crushes. I have a SplashScreen which should initialize the class with default values but it is always null.
Here is the call from splash:

```
LocalSettings.LoadSettings();
```

and here is the Class. PS: the SETTING variable is a table i used for saving datas on the local DB. It has same variables of LocalSettings class.

public class LocalSettings {

```
public LocalSettings(){}

private static Enums.TIPO_PERIODO periodoVisualizzato;
private static Calendar dataSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione;
private static Calendar dataInizioPeriodoVisualizzazione;
private static Calendar dataFinePeriodoVisualizzazione;
private static CATEGORIA categoriaSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione;


public static void LoadSettings(){
    List<SETTINGS> settings = SETTINGS.listAll(SETTINGS.class);
    if(settings == null || settings.isEmpty()){
        SETTINGS setting = new SETTINGS();
        setting.setPERIODOVISUALIZZATO(Enums.TIPO_PERIODO.SEMPRE);
        setting.setGIORNOINIZIOPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(Calendar.getInstance());
        setting.setGIORNOFINEPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(Calendar.getInstance());
        setting.setDATASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(Calendar.getInstance());
        setting.setCATEGORIASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(new CATEGORIA("", 0));
        setting.save();
    }else{
        SETTINGS setting = settings.get(0);
        setPeriodoVisualizzato(setting.getPERIODOVISUALIZZATO());
        setDataInizioPeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getGIORNOINIZIOPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
        setDataFinePeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getGIORNOFINEPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
        setDataSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getDATASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
        setCategoriaSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getCATEGORIASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
    }
}

public static void SaveSettings(){
    List<SETTINGS> settings = SETTINGS.listAll(SETTINGS.class);
    SETTINGS setting;
    if(settings == null || settings.isEmpty()){
        setting = new SETTINGS();
    }else{
        setting = settings.get(0);
    }
    setting.setPERIODOVISUALIZZATO(getPeriodoVisualizzato());
    setting.setGIORNOFINEPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(getDataFinePeriodoVisualizzazione());
    setting.setGIORNOINIZIOPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(getDataInizioPeriodoVisualizzazione());
    setting.setDATASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(getDataSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione());
    setting.setCATEGORIASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(getCategoriaSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione());
    setting.save();
}

public static void ResetSettings(){
    setPeriodoVisualizzato(Enums.TIPO_PERIODO.SEMPRE);
    setDataFinePeriodoVisualizzazione(Calendar.getInstance());
    setDataInizioPeriodoVisualizzazione(Calendar.getInstance());
    setDataSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione(Calendar.getInstance());
    setCategoriaSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione(new CATEGORIA("", 0));
}
//getters and setters below
```

I'm stuck here since some hours and even on the net I didn't find anything that solved my problem. Any help will be appreciated

EDIT:
this is where i get the nullPointerException, in "HomePageActivity":

```
TIPO_PERIODO period = LocalSettings.getPeriodoVisualizzato();
String periodString = period.name();
```

this is TIPO_PERIODO enum:

```
public enum TIPO_PERIODO{
    GIORNO, MESE, ANNO, SEMPRE, PERIODO_PERSONALIZZATO, CATEGORIA;

    public static List<String> ListAll(){
        ArrayList<String> tipi = new ArrayList<>();
        for(TIPO_PERIODO tp : TIPO_PERIODO.values()){
            tipi.add(tp.name());
        }
        return tipi;
    }
}
```

and this is the full stack trace:

```
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.piermisley.Activities, PID: 15902
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.piermisley.Activities/com.example.piermisley.Activities.HomePageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.piermisley.Classes.Enums$TIPO_PERIODO.name()' on a null object reference
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.piermisley.Classes.Enums$TIPO_PERIODO.name()' on a null object reference
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.piermisley.Activities.HomePageActivity.LoadList(HomePageActivity.java:100)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.piermisley.Activities.HomePageActivity.LoadPageDatas(HomePageActivity.java:438)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.piermisley.Activities.HomePageActivity.onCreate(HomePageActivity.java:80)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
10-14 12:50:55.196 15902-15902/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

EDIT: ps: my problem is not the exception, my problem is the null static class on first app's run. :)

Comment: try `if(settings.size() > 0 && settings!=null)`

Comment: @MD You probably wanna do the null check first.

Comment: @MD thanks for reply, i tryed it (with null before and size after) but it's still null on first run

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @MikeM. yeah, right. I will add a little piece of code that is the call which gives me null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @m0skit0 wel, i kinda know how to fix a nullPointer..xD my problem is in the static class, where i'm not an expert in.. not in the exception

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static class" in Java...

Comment: .... found the problem.. in the check on SETTING to exist, if not, i was only creating a new SETTING but not populating the static variables... so the first time they were null..

Comment: @m0skit0 solved, but before commenting read all the post, not only title :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Thanks for the tip on how to use StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you call `LoadSettings()` in the context of your application. Until you do, `periodoVisualizzato` will be null. Is "SplashScreen" an activity?

Perhaps you can call LocalSettings.LoadSettings() in your Application class in `onCreate()`, before any Activities have been created.

Comment: I will try it in a while, just a question: why the second run the null exception is no more showing?

Comment: Ok, now i'm at pc. the LoadSettings is in the SplashScreen ( wich is an activity).. that's why i don't get the fault

Comment: .... found the problem.. in the check on SETTING to exist, if not, i was only creating a new SETTING but not populating the static variables... so the first time they were null.. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, i was initializating the LocalSetting only if the SETTING entity did exist, if not i was only creating a new SETTING. thanks anyway all for replying. I just modified the clause with:

```
    SETTINGS setting;

    if(settings == null || settings.isEmpty()){
        setting = new SETTINGS();
        setting.setPERIODOVISUALIZZATO(Enums.TIPO_PERIODO.SEMPRE);
        setting.setGIORNOINIZIOPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(Calendar.getInstance());
        setting.setGIORNOFINEPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(Calendar.getInstance());
        setting.setDATASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(Calendar.getInstance());
        setting.setCATEGORIASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE(new CATEGORIA("", 0));
        setting.save();
    }else {
        setting = settings.get(0);
    }
        setPeriodoVisualizzato(setting.getPERIODOVISUALIZZATO());
        setDataInizioPeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getGIORNOINIZIOPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
        setDataFinePeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getGIORNOFINEPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
        setDataSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getDATASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
        setCategoriaSpecificaPeriodoVisualizzazione(setting.getCATEGORIASPECIFICAPERIODOVISUALIZZAZIONE());
```